# How can i get fiscal/financial year using dropdownlist in vb, the fiscal year month start at april until march

Tags: vb.net

Am trying to calculate fiscal year and it starts at april until march, and i want to use dropdownlist using visual basic.

am very new at vb and i would love to know how is done with an example f a code. I would appriciate that.

Comment: Please show previous code you have tried.

Comment: i just have the following at the moment...                                                                                                                                      If Not IsPostback Then                                                                                                          dropdwnlst.Items.Add("April".Tostring())                                                                                                  //until march, so am not sure how t do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding a Dropdown to your forms, you double click on that element. This will automatically add a new function to your code (indexchanged) and also add the mesages in the background.
When you now change to a new item at runtime this event will be fired and run the source code in that new created function.
There you can now get the index of the selected dropdown element the shown text or whatever you need to identify your fiscal period, abd then you can do whatever you need
In the future you will notice much more events exist, depending what you need.
I hope this clarifies somewhat.